# Scroll Reveal from Top to Bottom

Tags: javascript, scroll, reveal.js

I am trying to do something like scrolling a html element ***top*** to ***bottom***. But Now I have is scrolling from bottom to top. I have found some ways like scrolling from left to right or right to left. Is there any solution? I am using the Scroll Reveal Plugin from [here](http://scrollrevealjs.org/).

This is my **Html** Code.

```
<div data-sr="wait 0.8s">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <a class="btn ygn-btn" href="#">Download<i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my **Javascript** Code.

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    window.sr= new scrollReveal({
        reset: false,
        move: '50px',
        mobile: false
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation carefully whenever using a plugin.

The `enter` keyword controls the vector origin (direction) of your animation.

```
<!-- Reveal with a downward motion -->
<div data-sr='enter top'> Foo </div>
```

ref: https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollReveal.js/wiki/Keywords